# Appending text to specific patterns in a fasta BASH

Tags: bash, append, fasta

I have a fasta with headers like this:

> tr|Q7MX99|Q7MX99_PORGI_BACT

I would like them to say:

> tr|Q7MX99|Q7MX99_PORGI_BACT_ORALMICROBIOME

So basically, whenever I have *PORGI_BACT* I want to append *_ORALMICROBIOME* to each instance.

I'm sure there is an easy fix through the terminal, but I can't seem to find it.

My first idea is to do something like:

```
sed 's/>.*/&_ORALMICROBIOME/' file.fa > outfile.fa
```

BUT I only want to add to specific header endings, and that is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: My efforts have been a couple hours of googling to find the answer without much luck. My best effort has been to think about doing something like this: sed 's/>.*/&WHATEVERYOUWANT/' file.fa > outfile.fa but I don't understand how to do this for specific headers only

Comment: I figured it out after a lot of trial and error! I should probably get used to that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost close. Would you please try the following:

```
sed 's/^>.*PORGI_BACT/&_ORALMICROBIOME/' file.fa > outfile.fa
```

**[Edit]**
According to the OP's requirement, how about:

```
sed -E 's/^>.*(PORGI_BACT|HUMAN_MAM|TESTA_BACT)/&_ORALMICROBIOME/' file.fa > outfile.fa
```

Sample input as `file.fa`:

```
>SEQ0|tr|Q7MX99|Q7MX99_PORGI_BACT
FQTWEEFSRAAEKLYLADPMKVRVVLKYRHVDGNLCIKVTDDLVCLVYRTDQAQDVKKIEKF
>SEQ1|tr|Q7MX88|Q7MX88_HUMAN_MAM
KYRTWEEFTRAAEKLYQADPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDDVVCLLYRTDQAQDVKKIEKFHSQLMRLME
LKVTDNKECLKFKTDQAQEAKKMEKLNNIFFTLM
>SEQ2|tr|Q7MX77|Q7MX77_TESTA_BACT
EEYQTWEEFARAAEKLYLTDPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCMKVTDDAVCLQYKTDQAQDVKKVEKLHGK
>SEQ3|tr|Q7MX66|Q7MX66_DUMMY
MYQVWEEFSRAVEKLYLTDPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDNSVCLQYKTDQAQDVK
```

Output:

```
>SEQ0|tr|Q7MX99|Q7MX99_PORGI_BACT_ORALMICROBIOME
FQTWEEFSRAAEKLYLADPMKVRVVLKYRHVDGNLCIKVTDDLVCLVYRTDQAQDVKKIEKF
>SEQ1|tr|Q7MX88|Q7MX88_HUMAN_MAM_ORALMICROBIOME
KYRTWEEFTRAAEKLYQADPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDDVVCLLYRTDQAQDVKKIEKFHSQLMRLME
LKVTDNKECLKFKTDQAQEAKKMEKLNNIFFTLM
>SEQ2|tr|Q7MX77|Q7MX77_TESTA_BACT_ORALMICROBIOME
EEYQTWEEFARAAEKLYLTDPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCMKVTDDAVCLQYKTDQAQDVKKVEKLHGK
>SEQ3|tr|Q7MX66|Q7MX66_DUMMY
MYQVWEEFSRAVEKLYLTDPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDNSVCLQYKTDQAQDVK
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with multiple input patterns? Like looking for PORGI_BACT or HUMAN_MAM or TESTA_BACT and have ORAL_MICROBIOME added to the end of all headers that match?

Comment: Sure. I have updated my answer with the script based on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I tried that before, but used spaces between the text and the pipes. I see the right way now!

Comment: Year, a whitespace in the regex is not ignored but has its own meaning as a whitespace character which will be matched with the one in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -r 's/(^.*)(PORGI_BACT|HUMAN_MAM|TESTA_BACT)(.*$)/\1\2_ORALMICROBIOME\3/' file.fa > outfile.fa
```

Enable regular expression interpretation using -r or -E and then split the line into three sections based on "PORGI_BACT" being in section two and then substitute the line for the first and second sections, followed by "_ORALMICROBIOME" and finally the third section.

Comment: @Shem, I have amended the solution to add HUMAN_NAM and TESTA_BACT logic. Please test the amendment,